# Realizar una consulta a archivo dbf de Foxpro con c#

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-foxpro

Estoy trabajando en una app que se conecte a Adminpaq usando su SDK, he logrado extraer inf de Adminpaq usando las funciones del SDK sin embargo con esas funciones me es imposible acceder a algunos campos de la tabla que almacena informacion de la empresa, por ello decidi realizar una consulta directa al archivo dbf. He buscado ejemplos y este ha sido el codigo implementado.

```
        public void Empresas()
        {
        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection();
        cnn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=VFPOLEDB; Data Source = C:\Empresas\prueba\; 
        Extended Properties=dBase 5.0";
        //using (cnn)
        //{
        string consulta = "SELECT * FROM MGW10001";
        cnn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter adapted = new OleDbDataAdapter(consulta, cnn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapted.Fill(ds);
        cnn.Close();

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema?

Comment: El código que estás usando parece correcto, te falta incluir la pregunta para poderte ayudar

Comment: Bueno no me cargaban los datos y me arrojaba un error sobre el provider, descargue un driver de VFPOLEDB y con eso resolvi el error, tambien la ruta la tenia mal debia ser C:\Cpmpacw\Empresas\prueba\ pero eso ya fue despues